# How would you explain this SQL code in regards to select 1 from dual where exists

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to explain this to someone in laymen's terms.  How would you summarize this if you were talking to a 5 year old, lets say.

I would explain it as:

> *"find and display data that is from this table: a column from tableA where col1 = 5000 and col2 > ? and col3 > ? and col4 <= ?*

Is there a better way you can find to word this?  Thanks.

```
select 1 
from dual 
where exists 
(select 1 from tableA where col1 = 5000 and col2 > ? and col3 > ? and col4 <= ? )
```

Answer (score 0):

Me: *This query will return one row with a projection of `1` if there is at least one row in TABLEA where COL1 equals 5000 and COL2 is bigger than some unknown value and COL3 is bigger than some unknown value and COL4 is **not** bigger than some unknown value. Otherwise it will return no rows. It uses DUAL, which is a special table in Oracle guaranteed to return a single row.*

Five-year-old: *This code seems rather shonky. Did Spud write it? Can Bob fix it?*